# Immediately Display New Metrics

Tags: metrics, graphite

I am using graphite and coda hale metrics to try and track the number of times particular API's are called and also the top 10 callers. I have assigned a metric to each user who calls the API and use graphite to bring back the top 10.
The problem is, if it is a new user - ie a new metric, this will only be displayed in Graphite when the tool is refreshed - Has anyone come across a work around for this ? Is there some way Graphite can automatically detect new meters?

Just to be clear - I can see the top ten API callers for the last 30 minutes.........unless it is a brand new user that has never logged in before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that graphite-web uses an on disk index generated by a [glorified find command](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/0.9.x/bin/build-index.sh). Another script is [available](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/0.9.x/misc/rebuild_index.sh) so you can run it as cron to update the metric index file.

Whenever you update the index file, graphite-web process will [detect](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/0.9.x/webapp/graphite/metrics/search.py#L29) it and reload it.

Since reloading the index might be heavy for large (1M) number of metrics, I would advise to modify the update script a bit to conditionnaly update the file (only if different for instance).

EDIT: after test, graphite does not seem to call the reloading code